# How to send parameters across views in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

I have a silverlight navigation application template. 
For example. I have the home view and I click on something and I want to 
see for example the details view I would in HTML and in web programming 
send the querystring parameters like this details.aspx?id=34 into the 
details view, but now is the whole application just different silverlight views. 
Are there any good solution to this? 
Or am I forced to do several separate silverlight apps and fetch the querystring parameters
from the webpage instead?

Comment: Check out the Silverlight Navigation Framework. Basically Silverlight navigation uses bookmark URLs so that the page remains the same (and therefore the Silverlight app does not go away every time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the Silverlight Navigation Framework: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838245(v=vs.95).aspx and http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/The-Silverlight-3-Navigation-Framework.aspx

With help of this you can use this.Navigate( new Uri( "/Page.xaml?key=value", UriKind.Relative ) ); to navigate and send parameters.

With help of this.NavigationContext.QueryString[ "key" ] you can read out the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I recommand these two videos from Silverlight TV.

[Creating Navigation Structures in Silverlight](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/SilverlightTV/Creating-Navigation-Structures-in-Silverlight-Silverlight-TV-38)

and

[Advanced Silverlight Navigation Scenarios - Part 2](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/SilverlightTV/Advanced-Silverlight-Navigation-Scenarios-Part-2-Silverlight-TV-39)